# Write Single Array Dimension to Excel Sheet

Tags: python, windows, openpyxl

How can I write one dimension of an array to an excel sheet? I am using an [example](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#using-filters-and-sorts) from the `openpyxl` docs but it returns an error when I specify only one dimension.

```
TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict.
Supplied value is <type 'str'>
```

Code below but I will be using `ws.cell(row=i, column=j)` rather than `ws.append(r)`.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

data = [
    ["Fruit", "Quantity"],
    ["Kiwi", 3],
    ["Grape", 15],
    ["Apple", 3],
    ["Peach", 3]
]

for r in data:
    # ws.append(r)
    ws.append(r[0])

wb.save("filtered.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't just want to append to the end of the sheet. To use i,j as the top left hand corner rather than row 3, column 2 replace the loop with the code below using i instead of 3 and j instead of 2.

```
for r in range(len(data)):
    ws.cell(row=r+3, column=2).value = data[r][0]
```